# List showing messages

Tags: android

I am creating a messaging app like WhatsApp in Android. What is the name of the control that is used to display the messages? For example, if I open my chat history in WhatsApp, it'll display all my chat history with a particular user. Is it just a ListView or something else?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html read this docs to know more

Comment: any part in particular?

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: `Is it just a ListView or something else?`. Yes, it is. A custom one.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), I would suggest to take a look on this useful lib:
    https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter